# I want to create digital signature using DocuSign but I don't want to redirect user to DocuSign portal

Tags: docusignapi

I want to use DocuSign dll to sign the document but I don't user to redirect to DocuSign portal, is there any way to customize the DocuSign dll.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. ***Please check (select) the best answer for your questions!***

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is not much to me to go by, so here are some thoughts.

You don't have to redirect, you can instead embed in an iframe. this may solve the issue if your concern is that the URL is visible in the browser as DocuSign vs your URL.

However, if you just don't want to use a cloud provider then you need to use DSA (DocuSign Signature Appliance) which means you'll get a set of servers that you have to maintain by your IT dept and in theory you can have your users sign documents without connecting to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can *brand* the DocuSign signing ceremony to match your site's colors, fonts, add your logo, etc. See the [branding docs](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-admin-guide-configure-branding)

The signing always takes place at the DocuSign website. It can be embedded in an iFrame as Inbar mentions, but iFrames introduce their own issues.